# Spring boot Authorisation server access by Angular - keeps on giving CORS errors

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, spring-security-oauth2

Using "ng serve" I start an Angular application. The Angular app uses a post to get authorization on a Spring Boot (Authorisation) server.

Whatever I try, I keep on getting this response:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:9999/oauth/authorize 404 () Failed to load
>   http://localhost:9999/oauth/authorize: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 404.

**UPDATE: I will leave this post online, because it can help you step by step to solve CORS (cross origin) errors.**

I tried many ways to allow the Spring Boot application to enable CORS.

**Option 1**: addCorsMappings in the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   ... 
   @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
```

A variant on this is when you don't have a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class yet. Add this to your Spring Boot Application. See also the answer of @Maj.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}
```

Of course you can enable Cors more fine grained.

**Option 2:** add cors() to your WebSecurity adapter"

```
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        etc. 
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

**Option 3**: add a corsBean() to your security adapter.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();              
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
 configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","OPTIONS","PUT","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

**Options 4:** add a filter to your AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilterRegistrationBean() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(
         new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

**Option 5:** add a custom cors filter

```
public class WebSecurityCorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, x-requested-with, Cache-Control");
        chain.doFilter(request, res);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

In the websecurityconfigurer:

```
@Bean
WebSecurityCorsFilter myCorsFilter() {
    return new WebSecurityCorsFilter();
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(myCorsFilter(), 
                           SessionManagementFilter.class)
        .cors()
        .and()
            .formLogin().etc.
```

**Option 6**: remove security. Reduce the Spring Boot application to the bare minimum. Just for making a better diagnosis. Add the corsMapping() to the Spring Boot Application class.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
}
```

**Option 7**: There was a bug in Chrome in this area. So, I tried to use Firefox with a clean start.

**Option 8**: Convert the Spring Boot application into a web application. 
Nope. No difference.

**Option 9**: Wrong controller path?

Is this really a CORS error or an error indicating a wrong REST path?

The error message suggests, in my case, that it was a CORS error. But in the end, I was tricked by the way the context.path was introduced in the example code.

Comment: how are you serving the springboot app?

Comment: The spring boot app is served as an MAIN() application. NOT as a war via an application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking all options in the question, I finally found the issue.

After stripping the Spring Boot application to the bare minimum, I diagnosed the error.

The error suggested that it was a CORS error. But, it wasn't. I was tricked by the way how the context.path was used in this example.

So, it looked like a CORS error, but it was a WRONG PATH error.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue in which my angular app couldn't access my spring boot backand

I added this method in my security config:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:" + port") // angular port here
                    .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
        }
    };
}
```

However i converted to using an electron app later on and had to scrap security complete but i assume you absolutely require cors

Comment: I tried this also - see "try 1". I also seperated it from the surrounding class, like you suggested, same result.